# ssl with php payment page

Tags: php, ssl, https

I have looked at the other questions on SSL & PHP on this site and i'm still confused. I have never setup an https page before. I have read articles on ssl and know what it is, but I still don't know how to set it up with my php application hosted on an online Linux server.

I'm frustrated because after a lot of searching (even on this site) i'm lost on what my steps should be. Please help.

- I need to set this up with my payment page (member payment) and login page. I'm using codeigniter framework

Comment: If you are on shared hosting, ask your hosting provider or systems administrator how to do this. They will be able to tell you whether it's possible at all.

Comment: this doesn't look like shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming all else (server stuff) is configured properly, the only thing you need to do is redirect the page to `https://your-url` instead of `http://your-url`. It's completely transparent -- just make sure that all assets (external CSS/JS) are loaded using `https` as well if using absolute paths.

The best way to do so would be to include CSS/JS files via protocol agnostic links ( instead of `http://mydomain/mylibrary` use `//mydomain/mylibrary` and it will do it automatically. Images and such should be relative paths anyway.

Usually, the "server stuff" takes all the time to properly setup. However, these are beyond the scope of the question (I hope) since that would be best asked in https://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Note however that Serverfault.com is unlikely to welcome a question that merely says "how do I configure SSL?" they have a high standard of quality and if you have zero server admin experience, it might be better to hire a professional instead.